Gluestack-ui issue removing completely from application
How to remove totally gluestack-ui from my application? it completely modified my files, and I don't have anything on github, it's a project just on my laptop and i run gluestack init now i want to remove it but it added some files modified entire expo application how to do it ? any ideas for workaround or other best solution i can do now ?

In your packages.json , did you remove all the dependencies ?

yes I did, but this gluestack modified my styles and everything, nothing works as expected in natewind now.

No, obviously there is no other solution it modified also version of nativewind and etc.

Remove all packages related to glustack ui:-

remove the glustack wrapper from your app.tsx file.
remove gluestack-ui.config.json
remove nativewind-env.d.ts
remove tailwind.config.js
remove the components folder
Remove the related glustack components from your files where you have used it.


take care with this: remove the components folder. It should be: remove the components/ui folder
